# Avoiding np.where when assigning to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like for the following (or similar) to work (without using `np.where`)

```
>>> A = np.arange(0,10)
>>> ind = np.logical_and(A>4, A%2)
>>> k = np.array([0,1,0],dtype=bool)
>>> A[ind][k] = np.pi # Doesn't actually assign to A
```

That is, I want `k` to be an additional boolean mask on the values of `ind` that are true.

I know that I can use `np.where(ind)[0][k]`, but this is more expensive than logical indexing.

Is there a way to reference `A[ind]` that will refer to the base memory of `A`?

Comment: The problem is not `A[ind]`, but the `[k]` part. Without it it works (except that it assigns `3` instead of `np.pi`, because it is an integer array.

Comment: You haven't explained, what you intend to achieve with `A[ind][k]`. It is not obvious to me. Is k supposed to be an additional boolean mask on the True values in `ind`?

Comment: Yes, `k` is an additional boolean mask on the values of `ind` that are true.

Comment: So you want only the second instance in which `ind` is true?

Comment: You will need `k = [False, True, False]` or `k = np.array([0, 1, 0], dtype=bool)` otherwise it is not treated as a mask but as indices 0 and 1.

Comment: @kazemakase, If I replace the list with an array, the assignment still does not work.
@NilsWerner, I do not only and the second value of `ind` that is true. In general, `k` is just a boolean array of length `sum(ind)`.

Comment: No, but you still have to be aware of the difference between 0/1 integer and logical indices.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I ran a quick test and - strangely - where appears to be a bit faster. `min(repeat('a[mask] = 0', globals=globals(), number=100000)) -> 0.33872522017918527` `min(repeat('a[np.where(mask)] = 0', globals=globals(), number=100000)) -> 0.25470716995187104`

Comment: @PaulPanzer would you care to try if `flatnonzero` is faster than `where`?

Comment: @kazemakase did and it is slower. Sometimes I think my computer is just having a laugh...

Comment: `A[ind]` is advanced indexing (whether with a boolean mask or list of indices).  So it is a copy.  `A[ind][k] = ..` modifies that copy, not the original.

Comment: Isn't there something artificial about this?  The shape of `k` has to match the number of True values in `ind`.

Comment: Just to answer the "is this artificial question" here as well. This type of double boolean masking isn't artificial in my application. `A` denotes the quality of each point in a large set, and entries of `A` are updated each iteration. `ind` are the ones satisfying a simple-to-test condition and only for those points is a more expensive condition tested which is returned in `k`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the oft-referenced numpy indexing page:

> .... A single boolean index array is practically identical to x[obj.nonzero()] .... However, it is faster when obj.shape == x.shape.

`np.where(cond)` is `np.nonzero(cond)`.

But let's do some simple timing

```
In [239]: x = np.arange(10000)
In [240]: y = (x%2).astype(bool)
In [241]: x[y].shape
Out[241]: (5000,)
In [242]: idx = np.nonzero(y)
In [243]: x[idx].shape
Out[243]: (5000,)
In [244]: timeit x[y].shape
89.9 µs ± 726 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [245]: timeit x[idx].shape
13.3 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [246]: timeit x[np.nonzero(y)].shape
34.2 µs ± 893 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So array indexing is faster than boolean indexing, even when we use an explicit `where`.

---

`A[ind][k]=` does not work because `A[ind]` is a copy, not a view.

```
In [251]: A = np.arange(100,110)
In [252]: ind = np.logical_and(A>104, A%2)
In [253]: ind
Out[253]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
        True])
In [254]: k = np.array([0,1,0], dtype=bool)
In [255]: A[ind]
Out[255]: array([105, 107, 109])
In [256]: A[ind][k]
Out[256]: array([107])
In [257]: A[ind][k] = 12
In [258]: A
Out[258]: array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109])
```

But using the `k` to select indices from `np.where(ind)` works:

```
In [262]: A[np.where(ind)[0][k]]=12
In [263]: A
Out[263]: array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106,  12, 108, 109])
```

Timings for a fetch rather than a set:

```
In [264]: timeit A[np.where(ind)[0][k]]
1.94 µs ± 75.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [265]: timeit A[ind][k]
1.34 µs ± 13.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So yes, the double masking is a bit faster in this case, but that doesn't matter if it doesn't work.  Don't sweat the small time improvements.

### A boolean indexing method

```
In [345]: ind1=ind.copy()
In [346]: ind1[ind] = k
In [348]: A[ind1]=3
In [349]: A
Out[349]: array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106,   3, 108, 109])
```

In this small example timeit is basically the same as for `A[np.where(ind)[0][k]]=12`.

Comment: This type of double boolean masking isn't artificial in my application. `A` denotes the quality of each point in a large set, and entries of `A` are updated each iteration. `ind` are the ones satisfying a simple-to-test condition and only for those points is a more expensive condition tested which is returned in `k`.

Comment: I've come up with a 'pure boolean' indexing method, which appears to time the same as the `where` version.

Comment: +1 upvote.  I liked where you pointed us to [this reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).  I'm sure I'll go back to that a few times :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for small arrays (index the indexer!). Optimisation might be more tricky.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(0,10)
k = np.array([0,1,0])
ind = np.logical_and(A>4, A%2)

A[ind.nonzero()[0][k.nonzero()]] = np.pi
```

Comment: I think OP is aware of this kind of solution - they are just concerned it may be slow.

Comment: OK, understood. I'll leave it here if there are others who just want a solution that works for small arrays. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I found it helpful!  I imagine someone else will benefit from this answer as well