# What is the difference between arr1[arr1>255]=255 and arr1[np.where(arr1>255)]=255?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between `arr1[arr1>255]=255` and `arr1[np.where(arr1>255)]=255`  ?

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[[10,10,10],[20,20,20],[200,150,100]]])
arr1 = arr1*10
arr1[np.where(arr1>255)]=255
print(arr1)
```

---

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[[10,10,10],[20,20,20],[200,150,100]]])
arr1 = arr1*10
arr1[arr1>255]=255
print(arr1)
```

I find the result is same.

```
[[[255 100 100]
  [200 200 200]
  [255 255 255]]]
```

Comment: One requires a function call, the other doesn't.

Comment: They do the same thing.  In my testing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424130/avoiding-np-where-when-assigning-to-numpy-array, the `where` version is a bit faster.  But use which ever looks/feels best.

Comment: @hpaulj  Thank you!